# Mac OS X: Keyboard shortcut for moving active window to another screen

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

I'm using 2 Displays with Mac OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard) and I would like to have a keyboard shortcut to move the active window from one display to another (not space).

I just found answers for moving between spaces or one hint for windows:
https://superuser.com/questions/62603/keyboard-shortcut-for-moving-window-to-another-screen

Comment: Belongs on http://superuser.com

Comment: No, it belongs on [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Google brings you here... try out these two open sources ones:  http://spectacleapp.com/ and https://github.com/jigish/slate

Comment: You can even try https://splitscreenapp.com/

Comment: I found https://www.spectacleapp.com/ to work well. If anyone finds a question equivalent to this one on https://apple.stackexchange.com, would you put a link to it here in comments?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I use [SizeUp](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/), which has this feature and lots of other useful window management abilities.

Comment: SizeUp works the best compared with Arrange, Divvy, Cinch.

Comment: SizeUp is the best $13 I've ever spent.

Comment: I haven't tested the other recommendations, but SizeUp works just well for me.

Answer (score 9):

I use [Divvy](http://mizage.com/divvy/). Very good application if you have many screens and many windows open. There are always apps like [Cinch](http://mac.appstorm.net/reviews/utilities/quick-window-management-with-cinch/) which may be able to help.

Comment: "cycle between screens when using shortcuts" is the most helpful option for sending windows to a grid, back and forth.

Answer (score 6):

I use [Better Snap Tool](http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/bettersnaptool/id417375580?mt=12).

Comment: this tool works great, complete reproduction of Windows hotkey movement to reposition windows is possible, reach out if help needed!

Answer (score 1):

[Power Mover 2](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/power-mover-2/id516615326) is great for moving windows between displays with the keyboard.

Comment: It seems that Power Move 2 was pulled from the App Store?